# EventLog.readEvents() not working

Tags: android

I use following code in Android app to read event logs

```
    final Collection<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    try {
        final int tag = EventLog.getTagCode("am_proc_start");
        EventLog.readEvents(new int[] { tag }, events);
        System.out.println(events);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But what I got is an empty events list. Still I can get all these events by running command `adb logcat events -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add `android.permission.READ_LOGS` permission, then on Android 4.1+, use this shell command to actually grant permission:

```
adb shell pm grant your.app.package android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

Now I can successfully read all logs.

Comment: So no way to read the event log without the permission grant?